# AngularJS + SwitchCase for rendering different URL by clicking at List Items

Tags: html, angularjs, routes

I am begginer for AngularJs and In my angularapp I want to pass URL as per the selection of option from left menu. But I am not getting the way to access those.

```
<ion-content>
  <ul class="list">
    <a href="#/ShowItems" class="item" menu-close>Yahoo</a>
    <a href="#/ShowItems" class="item" menu-close>Google</a>
  </ul>
</ion-content>
```

**ScriptPage Template**

```
<script id="templates/show_items.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="Yahoo">
    <ion-content>
      <form class="list" ng-show="showForm">
        <div class="item item-divider">
          URL Info
        </div>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="text" placeholder="CurrentURL" ng-model="">
        </label>
        <div class="padding">
          <button class="button button-block" ng-click="submit()">Checkin</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

I am trying to add switch case in angular ( as per the selection of URL ) specific page will render.

Thanks a lot in advance.

**UPDATE**

Added few link in which way I want to show the page. I want the page title as per link clicked and rendering of that page inside the layout.

[CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/rpatil/pen/Esmlg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

HTML

```
<ion-content>
  <ul class="list">
    <a href="#/ShowItems" class="item" menu-close ng-click="item('yahoo')">Yahoo</a>
    <a href="#/ShowItems" class="item" menu-close ng-click="item('google')">Google</a>
  </ul>
</ion-content>
```

Controller

```
$scope.item = function(site){
      if(site == 'yahoo'){
            $scope.currentURL = "www.yahoo.com";
      }else{
            $scope.currentURL = "www.google.com";
      } 
}
```

And In input type place {{currentURL}} as you want.

Comment: But I dnt want to make separate pages for every click. In single page I want to render the clicked URL value.

Comment: Where you want to render the clicked URL value?

Comment: You can see templates/show_items.html having one input box. In that  I will put one switch condition and as per that I will change the content.

Comment: I tried as per your suggest but it is not showing anything. Means page render but value is not there.

Comment: I have edited the controller part check it. There will problem if you are going to render page in `<iframe>` as the **X-Frame-Options response header** for Google or Yahoo are set to deny.